# How to import data into Solr? Could anyone please tell me the baby steps?

Tags: apache, solr, solr4

I need to import a word doc to Solr. 
Could anyone please tell me the procedure to do this? Also the changes to be made in the xmls.

Answer (score 1):

Check [link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_0_0/tutorial.html). There are many other different ways to import your data into Solr... one can

> 1. Import records from a database using the Data Import Handler (DIH).
> 2. Load a CSV file (comma separated values), including those exported by    Excel or MySQL.
> 3. POST JSON documents
> 4. Index binary documents such as    Word and PDF with Solr Cell (ExtractingRequestHandler).
> 5. Use SolrJ for    Java or other Solr clients to programatically create documents to    send to Solr.

The question is too broad to explain.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have tried Indexing Data method.

Comment: i basically want to upload a document and verify if Solr is working or not.

Comment: @PPH The distribution includes data, configuration and utilities to submit the data to the server.